# Which dimensions do self-dual even Lorentzian lattice exists?

Tags: lie-algebra, spacetime-dimensions, lattice-model

I am reading page 499 of Peter West's Introduction to Strings and Branes where he stated 'Self-dual even Lorentzian lattices only exist in dimensions $8n+2$, $n=1,2,...$, the simplest such lattice is in dimension 2.'

This is self-contradictory, but I 've tried searching online and it seems there is no source for me to confirm. One page later we calculated explicitly the lattice coordinates and I was able to verify it for myself that the lattice in dimension 2 (i.e. $n=0$) is indeed an even Lorentzian lattice, but I fail to calculate its dual due to the short amount of materials presented in the book and my inability to understand everything.

My questions:

1. should $n$ start from $0$? I.e. self-dual even Lorentzian lattices exist in $D=2,10,18,...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there precisely exist self-dual even Lorentzian lattices in $D=8n+2$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, cf. Ref. 1.

References:

1. A. Kleinschmidt, *Lattice Vertex Algebras on General Even, Self-dual Lattices,* [arXiv:math/0210451](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210451); chapter 2.